# Generate new dataframe with values in old dataframe as new features in python

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas

I have a old data frame like:

```
Name  Courses      Attendence   Day
Mike    Math           1        Monday
Mike    Math           1        Tuesday
Mike    Physcis        2        Monday
Mike    Chemisty       1        Monday
John    Math           2        Tuesday
John    Physics        1        Tuesday
John    Physics        1        Tursday
```

And want to create a new dataframe:

```
Name  Math  Physics  Chemisry
Mike  2        2       1
John  2        2       0
```

Is there any efficient way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.pivot_table()`

```
pivoted = pd.pivot_table(data=df, columns='Courses', index='Name',
                         aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
```

Let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Comment: If it works, can you mark the answer? The check mark beside the question on the left side. Also, take your time to go through the SO guide and help. Welcome to SO!

Comment: The R equivalent `reshape2::dcast(df, Name ~ Courses, value.var='Attendence', sum)`